# Generating package.xml for deploying with Ant from Eclipse

Tags: deployment, eclipse

I'm using Ant to deploy from within Eclipse and facing a challenge of having to manually manage my package.xml files.

Currently I am unhappy that I a) have to manually manage my package.xml entries and b) can only deploy *all* objects in my project.

So these are separate but possibly related problems:

1. Can eclipse or the force.com plugin automatically generate the package.xml file for me?
   In some of my projects it is there and contains objects, in others it is empty. A refresh from server does not change it. I would expect it to at least contain all subscribed objects.
2. The sf:deploy target complains if there are files in the folder which are not in package.xml If I want to deploy only selected objects I have to manually generate a package.xml and make a new folder with only those classes.
3. Is there a way in ant to have targets use a different package.xml?

[target name="deployAll"]
   [sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" package="package.xml"/]
[/target]

[target name="deployBasic"]
   [sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" package="package.basic.xml"/]
[/target]

If anyone else is also using Ant I would appreciate some tips.

Comment: At least part of this appears to be a duplicate of this question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7447/generate-complete-package-xml-for-org

Comment: I did read that before posting and it confirmed my suspicion that my package.xml *should* be getting generated automatically via refresh but isn't :-(

Comment: 1.I am also trying for the same thing what you have mentioned like generating package.xml automatically. Have you got any solution for that???

Answer (score 2):

I am using ant together with Jenkins and indeed you need to generate the package.xml yourself or use that one from the eclipse project.

I found this salesforce migration guide very usefull to see what you can add in the ant script to retrieve/deploy

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for that link. It seems to definitely preclude specifying a different package.xml but that I can get around by using ant copy to overwrite the package with ready-made package.xml's

Comment: The next issue of sf:deploy not allowing any files in deployRoot which are not specified in package.xml will require another workaroun: I'm thinking of writing a batch file which zips the classes I want to deploy, adds a pre-made package.xml and thus deploys selected, pre-lackaged objects.

Comment: It would be helpful if I could limit a deploy to just what's in the package.xml file, without complaints.  Lacking that, scripts that build zipfiles are the next best thing.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the answer to my 2nd question is to use autoUpdatePackage="true". From the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf) p22:

> autoUpdatePackage: Optional. Defaults to false. Specifies whether a deploy should
>   continue even if files present in the zip file are not specified in
>   package.xml. Do not use this parameter for deployment to production
>   organizations.

Also, you can have a package.xml which specifies more files than you actually have in your deployRoot or zipFile if you use allowMissingFiles="true". Again the docu:

> allowMissingFiles: Optional. Defaults to false. Specifies whether a
>   deploy succeeds even if files that are specified in package.xml are
>   not in the zip file. Do not use this parameter for deployment to
>   production organizations.

The answer too question 3 seems to be No! See p23:

> You can deploy any set of components as a package or into your organization directly in 
>   the unpackaged package. The package used is not determined by the build.xml target, but 
>   by the project manifest (package.xml).

Comment: :-( Apparently you cannot have *more* files in your zipFile than are specified in package.xml - The documentation says it works with autoUpdatePackage="true" but it doesn't and generates "Not in package.xml" errors. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_deploy.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple shell or batch script that generates the package XML file based on the files contained in the folder to deploy. I have set up something like that for running my test classes individually rather than running all tests.

In regards to your second question, I haven't tried changing the name but I am quite positive it should work, at least it should take different package.xml files in different directories.

Comment: Indeed you need to either have a separate directory or use selective zipping (see above) to create tailor made deployment packages. Would be great if some eclipse guru could explain how to select say 3 classes and pass their name to a batch file... might need to write my own eclipse plugin someday since it seems the force.com IDE is NOT well maintained.